# Google Apps script : getting background color of text associated with checkbox to toggle between checked and unchecked states

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a UiApp written in Google Apps script that requires the background color of the text associated with a checkbox to change to green when checked and orange when unchecked. But I can't seem to get it to work. 
Do you know how I can get it to toggle between the 2 states?

Here's the sample code :

```
var checkbox = app.createCheckBox("Complete").setId(id).setName('id'+String(id));

var clienthandler = app.createClientHandler()
          .forEventSource().setEnabled(true).setStyleAttribute("backgroundColor","green")
         .forEventSource().setEnabled(false).setStyleAttribute("backgroundColor","orange");   

 checkbox.addValueChangeHandler(clienthandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can do this using [ScriptProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_scriptproperties) and a [server handler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_serverhandler/).

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('toggleColor', 'green');
  var checkbox = app.createCheckBox("Complete").setId('hi').setName('id'+String('hi'))
                    .setStyleAttribute('backgroundColor',  ScriptProperties.getProperty('toggleColor'));

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('toggle');
  handler.addCallbackElement(checkbox);
  checkbox.addClickHandler(handler);
  app.add(checkbox);
  return app;
}

function toggle(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var color = ScriptProperties.getProperty('toggleColor');
  var checkbox = app.getElementById('hi');
  if (color == 'green') {
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('toggleColor', 'orange');
  } else {
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('toggleColor', 'green');
  }
  checkbox.setStyleAttribute('backgroundColor', ScriptProperties.getProperty('toggleColor'));
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The client handler can do it as well:

```
  var textbox= ... define your textbox or get it by Id and give it a color 
  var clienthandler = app.createClientHandler()
     .forEventSource().setEnabled(true);// not really necessary in this case
     .forTargets(textbox).setStyleAttribute("backgroundColor","green");// assuming color was different by default
  checkbox.addValueChangeHandler(clienthandler);
```